# How can I subscribe and unsubscribe using onResume() and onPause() methods with RxJava 2?

Tags: rx-android, rx-java2, activity-lifecycle

Well, I need to bind emitting to my activity's lifecycle. How can I do that? And when should I create observer and observable instances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an observable that you want data from sometimes and not at other times, there is a simple way to subscribe and unsubscribe using the `switchMap()` operator.

Let's say you have an observable that want data from:

```
Observable<LocationData> locationDataObservable;
```

Then, if you introduce a switching observable:

```
PublishSubject<Boolean> switchObservable = PublishSubject.create();
```

you can control the subscriptions to the first observable:

```
Observable<LocationData> switchedLocationDataObservable =
  switchObservable
    .switchMap( abled -> abled ? locationDataObservable : Observable.never() )
    .subscribe();
```

To enable receiving the data, perform

```
switchObservable.onNext( Boolean.TRUE );
```

and to disable,

```
switchObservable.onNext( Boolean.FALSE );
```

The `switchMap()` operator takes care of subscribing and unsubscribing for you.

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved without Observable.never(). Just use BehaviourSubject with takeUntil and repeatWhen operators.

```
private fun getPauseUpdatesSource(): Flowable<Unit> {
    return setUpdatesPausedSubject
        .filter { it }
        .map { }
        .toFlowableLatest()
}

private fun getResumeUpdatesSource(): Flowable<Unit> {
    return setUpdatesPausedSubject
        .filter { it.not() }
        .map { }
        .toFlowableLatest()
}
```

And in the rx chain:

```
locationDataObservable
                .takeUntil(getPauseUpdatesSource())
                .repeatWhen { it.switchMap { getResumeUpdatesSource() } }
```

It just pauses your chain and doesn't emit any empty observables